# Краткое причастие или краткое прилагательное?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, причастия

Вот фраза: *работа хорошо **слажен(н)а.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Данная орфографическая тема не обозначена в ответах достаточно четко, а это особая тема – **различение причастий и отпричастных прилагательных.** Такие слова образуются путем **перехода** причастий в прилагательные. В полной форме в обоих случаях пишется НН, а вот в краткой форме начинаются проблемы – выбор Н или НН.

**Причастие**  определяется по следующим признакам: 1) обозначает признак по действию; 2) имеет прямое, а не переносное  значение; 3)  можно подобрать зависимое слово в Т. п. со значением производителя или орудия действия;

**Прилагательное** определяется по следующим признакам: 1) обозначает качественный признак, отвечает на вопрос каков. 2) имеет переносное, а не прямое  значение; 3) можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным; 4) возможны однородные отношения с другими прилагательными.

**Из словаря:** **СЛАЖЕННЫЙ**,  Согласованный, упорядоченный. С-ое пение. С-ые движения. С. квинтет. С-ая работа. С-ая труппа. С. оркестр. **СЛАДИТЬ**,  (разг.) С. дело (устроить, уладить).

**Решение**

***Работа хорошо слажена.***  Смысл вполне прозрачный – работа хорошо организована кем-то. Незримый **производитель действия** всё хорошо организовал.

Наречие «хорошо» действительно **подсказывает выбор,** потому что ***работа*** (какова?) ***слаженна*** (прил.) – это уже хорошая работа, так зачем же повторяться (плеоназм получится),  здесь и  **думать особенно не приходится.**  Так что второй ответ вызывает сомнения.

В современном ритме жизни наше **внимание становится скользящим**, мы перестали чувствовать родную речь.  А ведь достаточно просто **вслушаться** в сочетание «хорошо слаженна», чтобы понять его некорректность.

Прилагательное может находиться **в однородных отношениях** со словами с близким значением: ***слаженный*** – это хороший, гармоничный, согласный, согласованный, дружный, сработанный, упорядоченный.

А вот без синонимов или наречий   и **вне контекста** функцию прилагательного сложно определить, поэтому обычно однородные с ним прилагательные  присутствуют прямо в тексте.

**Примеры**

… его картина мира была так соблазнительно ***проста и слаженна***, что Артему даже не захотелось с ним дальше спорить. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

…дело сделано, свадебка **слажена,** обратно не вернешь. [Светлана Василенко (1998)]

**Примечание.** Интересно, что в первои примере тоже есть **наречие** "соблазнительно", но оно обозначет степень качества.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Из чувства благодарности за принятый ответ и для полноты изложения темы  приведу еще **примеры парных вариантов:**

мы **уверены** в будущем  – движения гимнаста чётки и **уверенны**;

море **взволновано**, люди **взволнованы** –  лица людей **взволнованны**;

нитки **запутаны** – жизнь сложна и **запутанна**;

выводы **обоснован**ы научными фактами – выводы точны и **обоснованн**ы;

дети **избалованы** родителями – они капризны и **избалованны**;

тучи **рассеяны** ветром – она задумчива и **рассеянна**;

всё хорошо **устроено** – квартира мала и **неблагоустроенна**.

Будет апрель, вы **уверены**? – Да, я уверен. Ты сливаешься с машиной в одно целое, движения четки, **уверенны** и плавны.

Все  они возбуждены и **взволнованы** предстоящими гастролями. Море **взволновано**, оно покрылось серебристыми бурунами. Непонятной тревогой **взволнована** грудь. На картине Маковского убогий нищий срывает со своей шеи крест, и лицо его **взволнованно**, бледно.

Она заметила, что леска **запутана** снова. История лабиринтов длинна, сложна и **запутанна**.

Никакое высказывание не может быть вполне **обосновано** фактами. Правила вычисления объёмов есть, другое дело, насколько они были точны и **обоснованны.**

Вы **избалованы** природой; она пристрастна к вам была.  Болонка может быть капризна и **избалованна**.

На свете чудеса **рассеяны** повсюду.  Ах, Король, как **рассеянны** Вы.

Множество скитов было **устроено** в чернораменских лесах. Люди **неустроенны** и хотят изменить свою жизнь.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Для меня это одна из сложных тем. Не до конца понимаю отличие кратких прилагательных от причастий. Правила довольно запутанны. Иногда выбор не так легко сделать.

Comment: Вы правы, тема сложная, часто здесь обсуждалась и всегда вызывала споры. И правила не очень помогают, каждый раз приходится думать.

Comment: Вот в ваших примерах всё предельно ясно. А как насчёт востребованный? Например: эти книги востребован(н)ы. Разве здесь не прилагательное? С одной стороны, можно же образовать сравнительную степень: эти книги востребованнее. С другой - в словаре это слово указано с пометкой "причастие".

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что в этой фразе (или предложении?) *слажена* — это краткое **причастие**.
**Работа хорошо слажена.**

Во-первых, имеется зависимое наречие "хорошо" (слажена *как?*). Это один из указателей, потому что прилагательное чаще всего зависимых слов не имеет.
Во-вторых, присутствует значение действия, процесса (работа сделана, устроена, согласована).

Сла́женный — страдательное причастие от глагола [сла́дить](http://endic.ru/academic/Sladit-58821.html) (по смыслу подходит и первое, и второе значение).
*Пьеса шла очень недурно: видно было, что она поставлена и **слажена** мастером* (С. Аксаков. Встреча с мартинистами).

Из Нацкорпуса:
Жест, пожалуй, условный, но композиция **слажена крепко** и потому кажется естественной. [О. Лаврова. Новые имена (1939.12.05) // «Советское искусство». № 85 (665), 1939]
Изба **слажена на славу**. Как художник, любовно выполнивший задуманную работу, не нарадуется он на создание рук своих: позванивает топориком, пробует, крепко ли в пазах, ковыряет ногтем конопатку, сухой олений мох…. [А. А. Богданов. Тайга разбужена (1925)]

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от контекста, например "Работа артиллерии и авиации была хорошо слаженна".

Comment: _Нацистская машина уничтожения была хорошо **слажена** и работала без перебоев._

Comment: А как насчет этого примера из https://ru.wiktionary.org:
Сегодня началось новое наступление, поддержанное слаженной работой минометов, артиллерии, танков, «Катюш» и авиации. В. Н. Гельфанд, «Дневники».

Мне кажется если речь идет об одной вещи, то она "слажена" в смысле "сработана", "сделана". Если имеется в виду, что две или более вещи скоординированы, то они "слаженны" - разве не так?

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: _А глянь ― надолбы-т из дуба **слажены**, в обхват бревно._ [А. П. Чапыгин. Разин Степан (1927)] Слажены = сделаны (не скоординированы).

Comment: Ну да, "слажены из дуба" значит "сделаны из дуба", поэтому одно "н". А вот если было бы "слажен[н]ы рядом, так чтобы лист бумаги не просунуть"?

Comment: Рядом, думаю, можно только сложить. 
_Стало совсем темно, и только лунный свет освещал блистательный пейзаж, а выгруженные «пупочки» были аккуратно **сложены рядом** со зданием, словно коробки с мебелью и магнитофоном._ [Егор Радов. Змеесос (2003)] Вообще-то разговор в вопросе идет о том, что работа хорошо слажена (= сделана).

Comment: Ладно, сдаюсь, до следущего интересного вопроса... вам пока что 1:0

Comment: Орфографический словарь
**слаженный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена (свадьба слажена); кр. ф. прил. (согласованный, упорядоченный) -ен, -енна (пение слаженно)**

Comment: Думаю, надо и без "хорошо". Просто: работа слаженна. Я склоняюсь к прилагательному.